# Custom design listview position error

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

custom design Listview Blog image

[image]

i want to create something like shown in the above image, where latest blog show up and other follow the alternate layout.

i have created the odd even follow loop, but its not working, when scrolling the listview it loads from first position,

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int layoutResource = 0; // determined by view type
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
    switch (viewType) {
        case 0:
            layoutResource = R.layout.news_row;
            break;

        case 0:
            layoutResource = R.layout.news_row_even;
            break;

        case 1:
            layoutResource = R.layout.news_row_odd;
    }
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);

    TextView txtNewsTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
    txtNewsTitle.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.activity, R.anim.fade_in));
    txtNewsTitle.setTypeface(Utils.getTypeFace(Utils.Fonts.ROBOTO));


    TextView txtMessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message);
    txtMessage.setTypeface(Utils.getTypeFace(Utils.Fonts.ROBOTO));
    txtMessage.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.activity, R.anim.fade_in));


    TextView txtAgo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ago);
    txtAgo.setTypeface(Utils.getTypeFace(Utils.Fonts.ROBOTO));
    txtAgo.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.activity, R.anim.fade_in));

    int MAX_WIDTH = Utils.getScreenWidth() / 2;
    int MAX_HEIGHT = MAX_WIDTH;

    final PNewsData news = (PNewsData) getItem(position);
    int n = 0;

    Log.e("position", String.valueOf(position));

    txtNewsTitle.setText(news.title);
    txtMessage.setText(news.description.substring(0, Math.min(news.description.length(), 120)) + "...");
    txtAgo.setText(news.added);


    if (news.images.get(0).path != null) {
        p.load(Config.APP_IMAGES_URL + news.images.get(0).path)
                .transform(new BitmapTransform(MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT))
                .into(imgNewsPhoto);
    }


    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At first **RECTIFY** [**`case`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) NO.

```
          case 0:

            layoutResource = R.layout.news_row;
            break;

        case 1:

            layoutResource = R.layout.news_row_even;
            break;

        case 2:
            layoutResource = R.layout.news_row_odd;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
if (convertView == null)
convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);
```

with:

```
if (convertView == null)
LayoutInflater inflater = getContext().getLayoutInflater();
convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);
```

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya Because OP's forget to mark this and went there from where no one returns  :D

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya buddy thanks but I dont want fake reputation, I like helping people and yes it feels good when in return I get some reputation.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Ok buddy I removed. Stay happy n blessed :)

Comment: No buddy I take this positively even i dont feel good to write that. In future I will not write this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is an error in switch statement. duplicated case 0.
And, add it

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 3;
}
```